# Using Python 3.7 on Pycharm gives me: "Error: Django is not importable in this environment"

Tags: django, pycharm, python-3.7

This problem just started when I updated to python 3.7 (on macOS). Is there any fix or is it an issue with JetBrains? I want to use Django 2.1 with Python 3.7

Also when I select "Run Server" despite the error, everything seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: What is "this problem"? Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Using virtualenv with python 3.7
Also I'm fairly sure it's just an issue on JetBrain's end not understanding how to deal with python 3.7
I've just reverted back to 3.6 for the time being, given that there's not really much of a difference between the two for the purposes of my work.
Pretty annoying but whatever for now I guess.

Comment: did you create a new virtualenv with python 3.7 and install django into it?

Comment: yes I did @Thomas

Comment: I have the same problems with Python 3.6 and Django 2.1. Are you sure, that Python 3.7 is the problem and not Django 2.1?

Comment: I think this is the corresponding bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31767

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps, in order to configuring virtualenv in pycharm:

- Select **File**, click **Settings**.
- In the left pane, enter **Project Interpreter** in the search box, then click **Project Interpreter**.
- In the right pane, click the gear icon, click **More…**.
- In the **Project Interpreters** dialog box, click the plus sign +, click **Add Local**.

  - Enter *~/virtualenvs//bin/python* in the path. If you followed the earlier post to setup a virtual environment for Python then enter *~/virtualenvs/api/bin/python*.
  - Click **OK**.
- Select **2.7.6 virtualenv at ~/virtualenvs/api**, click the edit icon.
- Check **Associate this virtual environment with current project**.
- Click **OK**.
- Click **OK**.
- Click **Apply**, click **OK**.

reference: http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/configure-pycharm-to-use-virtualenv/

Comment: Tried this and the message still shows. Nothing's broken, but PyCharm acts like it is. I think it just doesn't recognize 3.7 yet.

Comment: your virtualenv is on python 3.7??

Comment: What is we *dont want* to create a virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Run/Debug Configuration page
- Find Enviroment
- Change Enviroment vaialbles to: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;DJANGO_SEETINGS=your_project_name.settings

> You should show to Pycharm your projects settings file :) I hope it will work if you select correct Python Interpretet (venv)